# Expand collapse div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, sass

I'm trying to understand this `JQuery` code, I need to do it this way, I would use other kind of function but I will need to follow this way, I need to fix something, when you click on the `plus` symbol it should expand and show some content, the `plus` symbol must change into a `minus` symbol and change the color , that works correctly, and when you click again now in the `minus` symbol it should collapse and show no content, but that doesn't work, when you click on the `minus` symbol it collapse and expand again, I'm new to `Sass` and they are using it in here, I'm not sure to understand some `Sass` code specially the `&.expanded`, what does it means? I can't find in my html a class called `expanded`, but it is used in the JQuery. They put the JQuery code inside the _Layout file.

JQuery functions(`$(".contact_item.expanded")` ?? what does it means??):

```
<script>
        /* expand */
        $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {
            $('.contact_item.expanded .head').next('div').slideUp();
            $('.contact_item.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).next('div').slideDown();
        });
    </script>
```

And this is the Sass code I'm talking about, I don't understand very well the `&` sign:

```
 .contact_item {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #f1e7e0;
        background-color: #fcf6f5;
        margin: 3px 0px;
        float: left;

        &.expanded {
            .head .name {
                color: #f60;
            }

            .head .name span {
                border-color: #f60;
                color: #f60;

                &.plus {
                    display: none;
                }

                &.minus {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }

        .head {
            .name {
                font-family: "Tahoma";
                color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
                font-size: 11.1px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 7px 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;

                span {
                    position: absolute;
                    display: block;
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 20px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    border: 1px solid #706f6f;
                    text-align: center;
                    right: 15px;
                    top: 7px;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    line-height: 17px;

                    &.minus {
                        display: none;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is an image, you can see that `CALIFORNIA OFFICE` is expanded but when you click on the `minus` symbol it collapses and expands again...

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is the html using f12, now the `<div class="contact_item">` has changed to `<div class="contact_item expanded">` but in Razor it doesn't happens :

```
       <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        @{ var locations = LocationLookup.GetLocations(); }
                                        @{ int numloc = locations.Count / 2;}
                                        @{ var newlist = locations.Take(numloc);}
                                        @foreach (var loc in newlist)
                                        {
                                            <div class="contact_item ">
                                                <div class="head">
                                                    <div class="name">@loc.Name office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="icon"><img src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png" alt=""></div>
                                                            @loc.Address @loc.Continued, @loc.City, @loc.PostCode, @loc.State
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="icon"><img src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png" alt=""></div>
                                                            @loc.Phone
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        @for (int i = numloc; i < locations.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            <div class="contact_item ">
                                                <div class="head">
                                                    <div class="name">@locations[i].Name office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="icon"><img src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png" alt=""></div>
                                                            @locations[i].Address @locations[i].Continued, @locations[i].City, @locations[i].PostCode, @locations[i].State
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="icon"><img src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png" alt=""></div>
                                                            @locations[i].Phone
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

This is the html code using F12 in the browser, in here there is 
<section class="hidden-print" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="title">Contact us</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">



                                        <div class="contact_item expanded">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">California office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One Embarcadero Center Suite 500, San Fransisco, 94111, CA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (415)690-6214
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Florida office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        111 2nd Avenue NE Suite 1101, St. Petersburg, 33701, FL
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (727) 578-2800
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">London office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        Lloyd’s Building, Gallery 4 12 Leadenhall St., London, EC3V 1LP, England
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (0207) 101-9395
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Ohio office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        4449 Easton Way 2nd Floor, Columbus, 43219, OH
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (614)526-8754
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Pennsylvania office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One International Plaza Suite 550, Philadelphia, 19113, PA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (215)554-6777
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Texas office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        950 Echo Lane Suite 200, Houston, 77024, TX
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (281)653-6472
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Washington office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        1100 Dexter Avenue North Suite 100, Seattle, 98109, WA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (253)271-9692
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a sample fiddle?

Comment: You didn't posted any HTML. I think you should post the HTML too, or even better, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) like @Rajesh said. About the & symbol, it means that it's referencing the parent selector.

Comment: @lonut I made an update with the html

Comment: Please post the output html, not the razor.  And instead of a fiddle, make a snippet

Comment: There is a jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/1ctahoqu/

From there you can see that the expanding boxes were intended to function as some kind of harmonica control

Comment: Can you show a JS fiddle?

Comment: @Pete I've upload the html code concerning to this matter now, anything else let me know

Comment: @AlexGH nothing changes in your razor code because that is executed server side.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Thanks for all the info!! I works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's try to understand how jQuery selectors and SASS work.

a line that is intended to select elements in jQuery starts with the dollar sign (`$`) which is a shorthand for `jQuery`.

The selector is the parameter passed to this function. it works just like a CSS selector.

`var elementsWithAppleClass = $(".apple");`

will select all html elements that have the CSS class "apple"

The other thing is about how SASS works.

Sass is basically CSS with a bunch of syntactic sugar, so it becomes easier to write than normal CSS.

SASS allows you to nest CSS selectors. for instance :

```
.banana
{
   .pear
   {
      /* this style applies to all elements with the pear class 
         inside an element with the banana class */
   }
}
```

the `&` operator in SASS means that you are still referring to the above class, but what should happen if it also has the condition that follows.

```
.banana
{
   &.pear
   {
       /* this applies to elements that have the banana class, but */
       /* that also have the pear class */
   }
}
```

You could also use it to write styles for CSS states nested.

```
.banana
{
    &:hover
    {
       background-color:yellow;
       cursor:pointer;
    }
}
```

**On to your immediate problem :**

In order to fix your problem, all you have to do is check to see if the item you clicked is already expanded, and base your logic on that accordingly.

```
    /* expand */
    $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {

        if($(this).parent('div').hasClass('expanded'))
        {
           //this one is already expanded. we just need to collapse it.
           $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('expanded');
           $(this).next('div').slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
           //this one is not yet expanded. let's collapse all the other ones
           $('.contact_item.expanded .head').next('div').slideUp();
           $('.contact_item.expanded').removeClass('expanded');

           //now let's expand this one.
           $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('expanded');
           $(this).next('div').slideDown();
        }

    });
```

[Demo jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/843dpp11/)

Comment: Note that in order for this solution to look a little neater, you should not render the contact items with the `expanded` class.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I will explain what the `&.expanded` in SaSS  and `$(".contact_item.expanded")`in JQuery means with simple examples. (If not interested the answer to your question is below)

`&` refers to a **parent selector** in SaSS. It is used extensively when you are nesting styles. Let me give  you a simple example

```
div {
  &.red { //this is equal to "div.red" in CSS(div having class named 'red')
     background: red;
  }
}
```

In the above example, `&` refers to parent which is `div` & hence when SaSS compiles to CSS the above will render to `div.red` ... **`&` being `div`(the parent)**

Now the `.red`(class named 'red') soon after `&` means that the `div` has a class named 'red'. So you can assume the HTML to be like so

```
<div class="red">
  ... this WILL have background red ...
</div>
<div>
  ... this WILL NOT have background red ...
</div>
```

> Note: `div.red` is NOT THE SAME AS `div .red`, notice the space between div and .red. You could read about the difference from the link given below

Now coming to `$(".contact_item.expanded")` in JQuery, this means you are  trying to find an element which has the class named `contact_item` AND `expanded` in the SAME element TOGETHER. It will look for elements like

```
<div class="contact_item expanded">
  ... this div WILL get selected ...
</div>
<div class="contact_item">
  ... this div WILL NOT get selected ...
</div>
<div class="expanded">
  ... this div WILL NOT get selected ...
</div>
```

You could read about all the selectors [from here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

**FOR THE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION, YOUR JAVASCRIPT SHOULD BE -**

```
    $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {
       if($(this).parent('div').hasClass('expanded')) {
         $(this).next('div').slideUp();
         $(this).parent('div').removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
          $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
          $(this).next('div').slideDown();
        }
    });
```

Check the [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/XjzBwQ)

Put in simple words, you need also check whether the `expanded` class is available in the first place or not & then add or remove that class if required. Above code does just that.

Hope it helped.

Comment: it did help a lot!! Thanks!!